# Unity C#: A problem in moving objects across a defined path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create movement along path from one point to another using the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class FollowThePath : MonoBehaviour {

// Array of waypoints to walk from one to the next one
[SerializeField]
private Transform[] waypoints;

// Walk speed that can be set in Inspector
[SerializeField]
private float moveSpeed = 2f;

// Index of current waypoint from which Enemy walks
// to the next one
private int waypointIndex = 0;

// Use this for initialization
private void Start () {

    // Set position of Enemy as position of the first waypoint
    transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update () {

    // Move Enemy
    Move();
}

// Method that actually make Enemy walk
private void Move()
{
    // If Enemy didn't reach last waypoint it can move
    // If enemy reached last waypoint then it stops
    if (waypointIndex <= waypoints.Length - 1)
    {

        // Move Enemy from current waypoint to the next one
        // using MoveTowards method
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
           waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position,
           moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // If Enemy reaches position of waypoint he walked towards
        // then waypointIndex is increased by 1
        // and Enemy starts to walk to the next waypoint
        if (transform.position == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position)
        {
            waypointIndex += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

However, this part is not being triggered no matter what i tried:

```
if (transform.position == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position)
        {
            waypointIndex += 1;
        }
```

It only gets triggered when i put it in the update() before the movs function. If i add it after the move function in the update() it never gets triggered and the object never moves just like its original form.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Nested if in some functions sometimes give some errors. Have u tried to use a print method to see that whether your function goes inside of the second if statement or not. If you haven't, try that. And also, create another method and get a parameter which is in this case for your code is `waypointIndex` then try to call that inside of the `Move` method.

Comment: Nested if in some functions sometimes give some errors?? Programmers are the ones  sometimes making some errors ;)

Comment: Ahahahaha would agree you %100. Sometimes I think why I chose this major :D

Comment: Thank you for the feedback... Now i understand and managed to get it to work :)

Comment: If it helped, Im glad.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the character position with

```
moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime
```

the position will not be exactly matching any of the positions of your array because Time.deltaTime is the time since the last frame and it is a varying float with lot of decimal numbers. That makes the position not be "exactly" the same, so not triggering the part of the code you are interested in.
If you put it before, it makes sense that it works, because at the start() already in a exact position of your path, son the condition is true.

For the last if condition to be met, you would have to update the character position along your path through the exact points of it incrementing the index of waypoints[waypointIndex] instead of with Time.deltaTime.

For path following I suggest the Itween plugin, easy to use, can have cool curved path following, and to feasable understand implementation.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/itween-84

I can provide a trial script if you are interested and find it helpful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback... i got it to work by calculating the distance and comparing it to be smaller than a certain value.

Comment: you can mark it as accepted answer if you think it is, so people reading the question can find it straightforward

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, the problem was Time.DeltaTime gives the time between frames in seconds so it will never be equal to the number you are checking against and because you are checking position you can't do >= so using a current distance variable keeps track of how far it went. there are better ways to find the distance between points but i just did it quickly. Also you may have to change the index so you don't get an out of bound exeption on the first loop through.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class FollowThePath : MonoBehaviour {

// Array of waypoints to walk from one to the next one
[SerializeField]
private Transform[] waypoints;

// Walk speed that can be set in Inspector
[SerializeField]
private float moveSpeed = 2f;
float currentDist;
Vector3 StartPos;

// Index of current waypoint from which Enemy walks
// to the next one
private int waypointIndex = 0;

// Use this for initialization
private void Start () {

    // Set position of Enemy as position of the first waypoint
    transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update () {

    // Move Enemy
    Move();
}

// Method that actually make Enemy walk
private void Move()
{
    // If Enemy didn't reach last waypoint it can move
    // If enemy reached last waypoint then it stops
    if (waypointIndex <= waypoints.Length - 1)
    {

        // Move Enemy from current waypoint to the next one
        // using MoveTowards method

        currentDist += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
           waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position,
           moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // If Enemy reaches position of waypoint he walked towards
        // then waypointIndex is increased by 1
        // and Enemy starts to walk to the next waypoint

        if(StartPos == null) {
            if(waypointIndex == 0) {
                float StartPos = waypoints[waypointIndex-1].transform.position;
            }
            else
            {
                float StartPos = transform.position;
            }
        }

        float WaypointDist = Vector3.Distance(StartPos, waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position);
        if (currentDist >= WaypointDist )
        {
           waypointIndex += 1;
           StartPos = null;
        }
    }
}

}
```